# Can't add new attributes to existing model sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm quite newbie in sails.js. I need to add fields to an existing model in sails js.
Here it is

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id: {
            columnName: 'id',
            type: 'integer',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        username: {
            columnName: 'username',
            type: 'STRING',
            required: true,
        },
        userLevel: {
            columnName: 'user_level',
            type: 'integer',
            required: true,
            defaultsTo: 1
        },
...
```

But as soon as I add the fields in my model js like

```
   newAttribute: {
           columnName: 'new_attribute',
           type: 'integer',
           required: true
    }
```

I get an error "E_UKNOWN". 
To be more precise, when I try to login with updated model, I get this message:

```
rr {"data":{"err":{"error":"E_UNKNOWN","status":500,"summary":"Encountered an unexpected error","raw":{"code":"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR","errno":1054,"sqlState":"42S22","index":0}}},"status":401,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"data":{*email and password here*},"url":"auth/login","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Unauthorized"}
```

Appreciate your help.

UPD It's working if I set NODE_ENV to development. May it could be the problem with connection.js file?

Comment: I would suspect since you say that your new field is required, and your existing data does not have it, it will throw an error. Have you tried giving the field a `defaultsTo`?

Comment: Yep, I've tried it. Doesn't work

Comment: Darn. If you are in a development environment, have you tried setting `migrate: 'alter'` in `config/models.js`? This way sails will try to fix it for you. Still an experimental feature.

Comment: Yes,  I even tried to use 'drop', but the same error keeps occurring

Comment: Maybe something else can affect the db model

Comment: What database adapter are you using?

Comment: @Tholle I've recently tried to run the app with NODE_ENV set to development, and it's working! Now I'm wondering could it be the sails-mysql problem with production

Comment: @principalV Sweet! Nice find! I would guess it's done like that by purpose, so you don't accidentally destroy your entire prouction database :) That would be horrible. Maybe you have to migrate it manually in production.

Comment: @Tholle Seems so. It's working fine when I manually set NODE_ENV to development and then to production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that I've found the solution of my problem. At first I set NODE_ENV to development, and, I guess, the tables were created. Then I change NODE_ENV to production. And now it's working without odd errors.